# Retrieving JSON data from an Angular 8 with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I had deployed reading of JSON file from vanilla Angular 8. The result was displaying as expected on console.

But while, after integrating & deploying: an Angular 8 with ASP.NET MVC 5

Results turns out to be

> Http failure response for
>   http://localhost:60276/assets/mock-heroes.json: 404 Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

**app.component.ts(src\app\app.component.ts)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import SampleJson from '../assets/mock-heroes.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  arrHeroes: string [];

  ngOnInit () {
    this.httpService.get('../assets/mock-heroes.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrHeroes = data as string [];  // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        console.log(this.arrHeroes[1]);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**mock-heroes.json(src\assets\mock-heroes.json)**

```
[
    {
        "id": "11",
        "name": "Avengers"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "BatMan"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "name": "SuperMan"
    },
    {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "SpiderMan"
    }
]
```

How do I resolve the above issue after integrating with ASP.NET MVC?

---

**Edit:**

**hero.service.ts(src\app\hero.service.ts)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }

}
```

Comment: what port is your mcv app running on? also, doesn't your path start with /api/assets/...?

Comment: After specifying `this.httpService.get('src/assets/mock-heroes.json').subscribe( ...` it worked. As I'm new to TypeScript. But for some compilation error, I had shifted to other code. I will edit my post, you could suggest me to include the code snippets to `hero.service.ts` @GlennvanAcker

Comment: Oh, i see now, i thought the problem was that you were serving that mock from your asp.net mvc application. Also, Observables can be really annoying, especially if you don't have much experience with typescript and angular to begin with... make sure to do null checks, since an observable's data can be null or undefined while you're waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

The Final Solutions for Retrieving JSON data from the **`hero.service.ts(src\app\hero.service.ts)`** turns out to be from the below piece of snippet

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as MOD_HEROES from 'src/assets/mock-heroes.json';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService { // implements OnInit

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);

    for(let i=0; i<=MOD_HEROES['default'].length; i++){
      if(MOD_HEROES['default'][i].id == id){
        var person = {
          id: MOD_HEROES['default'][i].id,
          name: MOD_HEROES['default'][i].name
        };
        return of(person);
      }
    }
    // return of(h.find(h => h.id === id));
  }

  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>('src/assets/mock-heroes.json')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }

    /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  /** Log a HeroService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
  }

}
```

In the above snippets, I had parsed individual objects of an array, instead, if there are any built-in methods to accomplish. I will be hearing soon from posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> you have two options here:

`1) Import json directly as module`

> import data from './data.json';
>
> console.log(data) // => {title: "Simulating HTTP Requsts", content: "This is off the hook!!"}

`2) Move that json in assets folder'(Note: you have to reload stackblitz to make it working):`

> http.get('/assets/data.json')